# Give short name to Func<Type1, Type2> sequence in C#

Tags: c#, func

I have code like this:

```
private Func<Request, Response, byte[], string, string, Task> _started;
private Func<Request, Response, byte[], string, string, Task> _progress;
private Func<Request, Response, byte[], string, string, Task> _completed;
private Func<Request, Response, byte[], string, string, Task> _errorOccurred;
private Func<Request, Response, byte[], string, string, Task> _cancelled;
```

I'd better have something like:

```
typedef Func<Request, Response, byte[], string, string, Task> StatusUpdateAsyncCallback; // in C++ way.
private StatusUpdateAsyncCallback _started;
// and so on.
```

Can't figure out how to do this with Func. I'm used to delegates (where I didn't have this problem as I can give a unique name to any delegate) but now can't figure out how to repeat the same for Func declarations.

I'm migrating from simple declaration of a delegate type like `delegate Task StatusUpdateAsyncCallback(Request req, Response resp, byte[] data, string account, string alias)` because I'll now rely on some Func-specific abilities (for instance, it's possible to make an extension method which will work for all kinds of Func delegates with certain number of parameters while 'classic' delegates types are not compatible in this way). If more info needed on this, can be found in @Mant101 explanations at [How to write extension method which will make invocation list members in multicast C# delegate run sequentially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764794/how-to-write-extension-method-which-will-make-invocation-list-members-in-multica)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `using` (in every file):

```
using StatusUpdateAsyncCallback = 
      System.Func<Request, Response, byte[], string, string, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>;
```

All type names should be fully-qualified.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a type alias using `using`, although it's only going to apply within that file, not the rest of the assembly.

```
using StatusUpdateAsyncCallback = 
    System.Func<Request, Response, byte[], string, string, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>;
```

Comment: Yes, I did try that in the first place but it never worked out. After your suggestion, I tried it again but still getting 'Type or namespace Func could not found'. I tried with smaller number of parameters as well (like `using StatusUpdateAsyncCallback = Func<int>;`). But oh my lord, I got it working finally, it turns out full type name System.Func is always needed, using System in the beginning of the source is not enough.

Comment: @Alex Type aliases always require fully-qualified type names.  They're independent of any other usings that might be present.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the same source file, this will work:

```
using StatusUpdateAsyncCallback = System.Func<Request, Response, byte[], string, string, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>;
```

The key point is to always provide full type names in using directive (`System.Func`, `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`). Earlier `using System.Threading.Tasks` and `using System` declarations have no effect.